# What factors influence whether an invention is not patented?

Tags: reference-request, history, economic-history, intellectual-property

Various inventions that have become well-known were [never patented](https://www.davison.com/blog/inventions-that-are-surprisingly-not-patented/), including matches, emoticons, and the magnetic strip. Other noteworthy examples include the polio vaccine (Jonas Salk), monoclonal antibodies (Cesar Milstein), the scanning tunneling microscope (IBM scientists Binnig and Rohrer), and the penicillin (invented and deliberately not patented by Fleming, later patented by Coghill and Moyer in the US).

**Question**: I am interested in systemic, empirical, and statistical studies that look into such unpatented inventions in more detail. More specifically, I am curious as to what different factors influenced why certain inventions were not patented. Was it because of certain political ideals of the inventor, not filing on time, the invention being too much akin to other products or inventions, or something else?

I've searched on Google Scholar with combinations of various key words, including "patent", "statistical", "analysis", "unpatented", "factors", "prior", "art", "political", and "economy", but I couldn't find much on this particular question.

*Note*: I've also asked a shorter version of this [question](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/25054/systemic-analysis-of-unpatented-inventions) on Patents SE, Law SE, and History SE. On the former platform, I haven't received any answers yet - users have commented I'm unlikely to find any answers there because they're more knowledgeable about the patents themselves than about the history behind them. On the latter platform, I made the [the question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/70390/what-factors-influence-whether-an-invention-is-not-patented) a bit too broad, so it was closed. Therefore, I've made it more focussed for the Economics SE platform.